# MVC TextBoxFor Placeholder text alignment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this control in the MVC view page as

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TemplateGroupName, 
  new { tabindex = "1",  placeholder = "Enter Template Group Name" })
```

Generated Control markup:-

```
    <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" 
      data-val-required="The TemplateGroupName field is required."       
id="TemplateGroupName" name="TemplateGroupName" 
placeholder="Enter Template Group Name" 
tabindex="1" value="" type="text">
```

I am trying to center-align the placeholder text. 
Please suggest.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f1qb7j0/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place following css on your page. It will center align placeholder in all browsers:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   text-align: center;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align: center;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align: center;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   text-align: center; 
}
```

OR

you can implement the styling to a particular textbox like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TemplateGroupName, 
  new { tabindex = "1",  placeholder = "Enter Template Group Name", Style = "text-align:center;" })
```

Comment: Yes.. First one will work for all textboxes on the page and will center align only placeholders not the text entered by user. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Aligning the content within the textbox in MVC we use 'Text-Align' Property.

```
@Html.TextBox("Name",new{placeholder="Your Text",style="Text-align:Center"});
```